# explicit formulae of heat kernel on graphs

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, spectral-graph-theory, heat-equation

I have just discovered [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.2096.pdf) about heat kernels on graphs. It has been written by a respected theoretical physicist, but seemingly never made it into a peer-reviewed journal. On the other hand, the paper offers formulae of some interest, given how little is known about discrete heat kernels even in simple graph configurations; but it has virtually never been quoted. Is anybody aware of this paper? Are its results known to be correct/uncorrect?